# Combine existing bundled JavaScript WebPack module with TypeScript and re-bundle them

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, excel-formula

I have converted my angularjs application from javascript to typescript and I tried different ways to import formula-parser https://github.com/handsontable/formula-parser/ to typescript and defined formulaParser in typings.d.ts but formulaParser always is undefined.

```
import "./formula-parser.js";

import   formulaParser from "./formula-parser"

var parser = new formulaParser.Parser();
```

I couldn't find any appropriate solution so I just defined formulaParser as

```
 var formulaParser: any;
```

and included the js file in the html page without any bundling.

Comment: Can you also provide information about how you declared formularParser in typings.d.ts?

Comment: I've defined it as var : declare var formulaParser;

Comment: I think you need to have the export keyword (but not sure)